# Rock Paper Scissors abstraction in Python

Tags: python, abstraction

I did a senior Python backend engineer interview that involved implementing a Rock Paper Scissors game. The result was not pretty. Their engineer said I have clumsy implementation all over the place. I did an upgrade afterwards, but still have one issue that confuses me. They would like me to change my original implementation of the game rules to a better abstraction.

My original implementation is:

```
def _outcome(self, player_move, ai_move):
    """Determine the outcome of current round.

    Paper beats (wraps) rock.
    Rock beats (blunts) scissors.
    Scissors beats (cuts) paper.

    Parameters
    ----------
    player_move : MoveChoice
        Player's move for current round.

    ai_move : MoveChoice
        AI's move for current round.

    Returns
    -------
    outcome : Outcome
        Outcome of the current round.
    """
    if player_move == 1 and ai_move == 2 or \
        player_move == 2 and ai_move == 3 or \
        player_move == 3 and ai_move == 1:
        return self.computer.name
    elif player_move == 1 and ai_move == 3 or \
        player_move == 2 and ai_move == 1 or \
        player_move == 3 and ai_move == 2:
        return self.player.name
    else:
        return 'Draw'
```

with a mapping:

```
MOVE_CHOICE = {
    1: 'rock',
    2: 'paper',
    3: 'scissors',
}
```

I have a `role.Player` and `role.Computer` class defined elsewhere. Their critiques are:

- Use of strings (player name or “draw”) to represent the outcome of a round
- No abstraction of the game rules, just a couple of big Boolean expression testing all combinations 1 by 1

Their suggestions are:

- Modelling moves (rock, paper, scissors) as an Enum
- Modelling round outcomes (win, lose, draw) as an Enum
- Modelling the games rules as either a function that takes 2 moves and returns an outcome, or as a dict mapping a move to a list of moves over which it wins

So far I've created Enums for Moves and Outcome:

```
class MoveChoice(Enum):
    ROCK = auto()
    PAPER = auto()
    SCISSORS = auto()


class Outcome(Enum):
    WIN = auto()
    LOSE = auto()
    DRAW = auto()
```

But I'm having trouble abstracting the game rules like they asked. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you've shown and the recommendations they gave you, I would do something like this:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class MoveChoice(Enum):
    ROCK = auto()
    PAPER = auto()
    SCISSORS = auto()

class Outcome(Enum):
    WIN = auto()
    LOSE = auto()
    DRAW = auto()

WIN_MAPPING = {
    MoveChoice.ROCK: MoveChoice.SCISSORS,
    MoveChoice.SCISSORS: MoveChoice.PAPER,
    MoveChoice.PAPER: MoveChoice.ROCK,
}

def outcome(player_move, ai_move):
    if player_move == ai_move:
        return Outcome.DRAW
    elif WIN_MAPPING[player_move] == ai_move:
        return Outcome.WIN
    else:
        return Outcome.LOSE
```

Note that I've changed your method to a function. This isn't a recommendation on overall program structure, it's just to present the logic as a more self-contained example.

---

As [Luke Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15963311/luke-nelson) pointed out in the comments, the interviewers suggested that the win mapping map each move to a *list* of moves it beats. I missed this detail. While it doesn't make any practical difference in Rock Paper Scissors, it is more generalized, and would make it easier if they then ask you to expand the rule set to something like [Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock](http://www.samkass.com/theories/RPSSL.html).

The only thing that would change about the mapping would be turning each value into a single-element list:

```
WIN_MAPPING = {
    MoveChoice.ROCK: [MoveChoice.SCISSORS],
    MoveChoice.SCISSORS: [MoveChoice.PAPER],
    MoveChoice.PAPER: [MoveChoice.ROCK],
}
```

Then the `outcome` function, instead of checking if the computer's move *equals* the value, would have to check if it's *in* the value (since the value is now a list).

```
def outcome(player_move, ai_move):
    if player_move == ai_move:
        return Outcome.DRAW
    # elif WIN_MAPPING[player_move] == ai_move:
    # Above line is replaced with:
    elif ai_move in WIN_MAPPING[player_move]:
        return Outcome.WIN
    else:
        return Outcome.LOSE
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Just wanted to note that they did ask for the dict to map to a list of moves that your choice can win over. ie. Maybe the values of WIN_MAPPING could be single-element lists and you could check `elif ai_move in WIN_MAPPING[player_move]:`. This would prepare for a followup task such as "Now convert the game to rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock."

Comment: @LukeNelson Could you write a solution as well for your idea? Based on CrazyChucky's answer

Comment: @YehuiHe I mean... that's pretty much it. Just change those two things Luke mentioned. I agree though, it does more accurately fulfill the exact wording I hadn't noticed, and is more extendable.

Comment: I wouldn't want to take away any credit from this great answer. @CrazyChucky perhaps you want to just include it in an edit? (Sadly, comments can disappear)

Comment: Done, thank you. @YehuiHe, you might be interested in browsing the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). This particular question is narrow enough (and about dummy code) that it's on-topic for SO, but in general, SO is a much better place to learn about nuts-and-bolts details, while Software Engineering has a wealth of information about design philosophy and how to best structure programs in the broader sense. Metaphorically, SO is about how to write dialogue; Software Engineering is about how to structure a plot.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Ok seems their developer means literally. Again beautiful solution. My comments disappeared. And thanks for SE suggestions.